# Flask Restful API request/response time monitoring

Tags: python, rest, flask, flask-restful

I have a flask application which has multiple REST API's. I need a method to track or record the time taken by each and every API request. I need a way wherein I could capture the timings of various request methods.

Comment: Have you tried flask-profiler? https://github.com/muatik/flask-profiler

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to achieve this.

a) Write your own monitoring logic. For example, you could utilise Flask's [@before_request](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#flask.Flask.before_request) and [@after_request](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#flask.Flask.after_request) hooks to capture response times for all requests, write them to a database and then query your database for analytics.

```
from datetime import datetime
from flask import g

@app.before_request
def start_timer():
    g.start_time = datetime.now()

@app.after_request
def log_time(response):
    elapsed_time = datetime.now() - g.start_time
    # Insert into database ...
    return response
```

b) Use a simple API traffic monitoring solution, such as [Apitally](https://apitally.io), which can provide you with the insights you're after with very little effort.

c) Use a more comprehensive third-party monitoring solution, such as New Relic, Datadog etc.

d) Set up your own monitoring infrastructure, for example using Prometheus and Grafana. You could export Flask metrics to Prometheus using [prometheus-flask-exporter](https://github.com/rycus86/prometheus_flask_exporter).

e) Depending on how your Flask application is deployed, you could configure your web server to include response times in the request logs and then analyze those.

*(Disclaimer: I'm the author of Apitally).*